# Troubles when installing R with readline

Tags: r, installation, readline

The readline libraries are required for having comand line completion etc. in R. I installed readline from source, but when I run `./configure` on the R-3.1.1 source, I get the following error:

```
....
checking readline/history.h usability... yes
checking readline/history.h presence... yes
checking for readline/history.h... yes
checking readline/readline.h usability... yes
checking readline/readline.h presence... yes
checking for readline/readline.h... yes
checking for rl_callback_read_char in -lreadline... no
checking for main in -lncurses... no
checking for main in -ltermcap... no
checking for main in -ltermlib... no
checking for rl_callback_read_char in -lreadline... no
checking for history_truncate_file... no
configure: error: --with-readline=yes (default) and headers/libs are not available
```

So apparently, readline is installed and is found - but not all the required packages? What is the problem here and how can I fix it?